# Why are C++11 override and final not attributes?

Tags: c++, c++11

I somehow missed that attributes were introduced in C++11. Now I found out, I'm wondering why `override` and `final` were added as *identifiers with special meaning* and not as standard attributes.

The purpose of `override` is to generate a compile time error and this is also the purpose of many of the standard attributes. It feels as if they would fit in that concept but there is probably a reason for it that I'm missing.

Comment: Why is `noexcept` not one? Questions of the universe.

Comment: "this is also the purpose of many of the standard attributes" really? Which one?

Comment: @GillBates Because it is an expression with a return value?

Comment: @T.C. For example deprecated and fallthrough also does compile time checks.

Comment: Those do not generate "compile time error"s.

Comment: @T.C. True, my question could have been clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They were, once, before they got changed in response to comment [US 44](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3224.html#US44) on C++11's FCD:

> Even if attributes continue to be standardized over continued
>   objections from both of the two vendors who are cited as the principal
>   prior art, we can live with them with the exception of the virtual
>   override controls. This result is just awful, as already shown in the
>   example in 7.6.5 (excerpted):
>
> ```
> class D [[base_check]] : public B {
>     void some_func [[override]] ();
>     virtual void h [[hiding]] (char*); 
> };
> ```
>
> Here we have six keywords (not counting `void` and `char`): three normal
>   keywords, and three `[[decorated]]` keywords. There has already been
>   public ridicule of C++0x about this ugliness. This is just a poor
>   language design, even in the face of backward compatibility concerns
>   (e.g., that some existing code may already use those words as
>   identifiers) because those concerns have already been resolved in
>   other ways in existing practice (see below). More importantly, this is
>   exactly the abuse of attributes as disguised keywords that was
>   objected to and was explicitly promised not to happen in order to get
>   this proposal passed. The use of attributes for the virtual control
>   keywords is the most egregious abuse of the attribute syntax, and at
>   least that use of attributes must be fixed by replacing them with
>   non-attribute syntax. These virtual override controls are language
>   features, not annotations.
>
> It is possible to have nice names and no
>   conflicts with existing code by using contextual keywords, such as
>   recognizing the word as having the special meaning when it appears in
>   a grammar position where no user identifier can appear, as
>   demonstrated in C++/CLI which has five years of actual field
>   experience with a large number of customers (and exactly no name
>   conflict or programmer confusion problems reported in the field during
>   the five years this has been available):
>
> ```
> class D : public B {
>     void some_func() override; // same meaning as [[override]] - explicit override
>     virtual void h (char*) new; // same meaning as [[hiding]] - a new function, not an override
> };
> int override = 42; // ok, override is not a reserved keyword
> ```
>
> The above forms are implementable, have been implemented, have years
>   of practical field experience, and work. Developers love them. Whether
>   the answer is to follow this existing practice or something else,
>   there needs to be a more natural replacement for the currently
>   `[[attributed]]` keywords for virtual override control which is an ugly
>   novelty that has no field experience and that developers have already
>   ridiculed.

Answer (score 0):

To simply quote http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes:

> Attributes provide the unified standard syntax for implementation-defined language extensions, such as the GNU and IBM language extensions **attribute**((...)), Microsoft extension __declspec(), etc.

This makes it quite clear that standard language keywords are not attributes.

Comment: I think the question is asking *why* those keywords are keywords, rather than being implemented as attributes, such as other standard attributes like `[[noreturn]]`.